# Pagination issue in tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have one tableview.In tableview each page there is 16 data.

For that I am calling one `webservice`

First I am passing Pagin Zero.

```
      [self callAPI:0];

-(void)callAPI:(int)page1{
   [dictParams setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pagin]  forKey:@"pagin"];
 }
```

When I scrolldown new data is reloading.But when scroll up to tableview last data is not showing. Here is my code:

perPage = 16;

this is my code for paging

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
    if(self.tblArticle.contentOffset.y >= (self.tblArticle.contentSize.height - self.tblArticle.bounds.size.height))
    {
        if(isPageRefreshing==NO){
            isPageRefreshing=YES;
            [self callAPI:perPage];
        }
    }
      else {
      }
    }
```

My requirement is first time pagin value is zero.Each time it will be pagin value + 16

when I scrollup I am not getting last data in tableview.

Can you help me to find out solution?

Comment: you probably override your datasource array with the new data, thus your tableview wont show old data, you might need to check if you replace or append data correctly or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one array from which you fill tableview. So you have to insert every new data to that array.

e.g, in success response of Api,

[yourArr addObjectFromArray:_responseArr]

- then reload tableview

Comment: amazing brother.its working. but what if data is fully loaded.and it is last row

Comment: I didnt get your question.

Comment: suppose i am loading data in tableview.and data is not available from websevice.so what should i do

Comment: check condition if responseArr.count > 0 then only [yourArr addObjectFromArray:_responseArr]